How to Perform Testing with xUnit and Mock with an In-Memory Database?
In ASP.NET Core 6, I'm using MariaDB and have a Controller that injects IService via dependency injection in its constructor. The Service injects its IRepository, which inherits from a GenericRepository that contains the DBContext injection. I want to use an in-memory database during testing, so I created DataBaseFixture : IDisposable, which also populates some data. However, I'm having difficulty implementing the tests and specifying that the context from DataBaseFixture should be used.
ArtistaController.cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ArtistaController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IArtistaService _artistaService;

    public ArtistaController(IArtistaService context)
    {
        _artistaService = context;
    }
    ...
}

ArtistaService.cs
public class ArtistaService : IArtistaService
{
    private readonly IArtistaRepository _artistaRepository;
    private readonly IContextRepository _contextRepository;

    public ArtistaService(IArtistaRepository artistaRepository, IContextRepository contextRepository)
    {
        _artistaRepository = artistaRepository;
        _contextRepository = contextRepository;
    }
    ...
}

ArtistaRepository.cs
public class ArtistaRepository : GenericRepository<ArtistaModel>, IArtistaRepository
{
    public ArtistaRepository(OrientoonContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }
}

GenericRepository.cs
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly OrientoonContext _context;
    protected readonly DbSet<T> _dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(OrientoonContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _dbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }
    ...
}

DataBaseFixture.cs
public class DataBaseFixture : IDisposable
{
    public OrientoonContext Context { get; private set; }

    public DataBaseFixture()
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<OrientoonContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            .Options;
        
        Context = new OrientoonContext(options);

        SeedDatabase();
    }

    private void SeedDatabase()
    {
        Context.Artista.AddRange(
            new ArtistaModel { Id = "1", nome = "Oda" },
            new ArtistaModel { Id = "2", nome = "Echiro" },
            new ArtistaModel { Id = "3", nome = "Echiro Oda" }
        );
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
        Context.Dispose();
    }
}

The result is always returning null, and I've tried various approaches.
ArtistaControllerTest.cs
public class ArtistaControllerTest : IClassFixture<DataBaseFixture>
{
    private readonly DataBaseFixture _fixture;

    private readonly Mock<IArtistaService> _artistaServiceMock;
    private readonly ArtistaController _controller;

    public ArtistaControllerTest(DataBaseFixture fixture)
    {
        _fixture = fixture;
        _artistaServiceMock = new Mock<IArtistaService>();
        _artistaServiceMock.Setup(service => service.GetAsync(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync((string id) =>
        {
            var artista = _fixture.Context.Artista.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
            return new ArtistaForm { Id = artista.Id, Nome = artista.nome };
        });
        _controller = new ArtistaController(_artistaServiceMock.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async void GetArtista()
    {
        var artistaId = "1";
        var expectedArtista = new ArtistaModel { Id = artistaId, nome = "Oda" };

        var result = await _controller.Get(artistaId);

        // Assert
        var okResult = Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(result.Result);
        var returnValue = Assert.IsType<ArtistaForm>(okResult.Value);
        Assert.Equal(expectedArtista.Id, returnValue.Id);
        Assert.Equal(expectedArtista.nome, returnValue.Nome);
    }
}

I tried setting up unit tests for my ASP.NET Core application using xUnit and Moq with an in-memory database. I expected the tests to correctly use the seeded data from the in-memory database and return the expected results. However, the results were always null. Specifically, I wanted the ArtistaController to retrieve an ArtistaModel object based on its ID, but despite the setup, the test did not return the expected data from the in-memory database.

Here is a whole working demo you could follow:
Services
public interface IArtistaService
 {
     Task<ArtistaForm> GetAsync(string id);
 }

 public interface IArtistaRepository : IGenericRepository<ArtistaModel>
 {
     Task<ArtistaModel> GetByIdAsync(string id);
 }

 public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
 {
     Task AddAsync(T entity);
     Task DeleteAsync(T entity);
     Task UpdateAsync(T entity);
     Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync();
     Task<T> GetByIdAsync(string id);
 }
 public class ArtistaService : IArtistaService
 {
     private readonly IArtistaRepository _artistaRepository;

     public ArtistaService(IArtistaRepository artistaRepository)
     {
         _artistaRepository = artistaRepository;
     }

     public async Task<ArtistaForm> GetAsync(string id)
     {
         var artista = await _artistaRepository.GetByIdAsync(id);
         if (artista == null) return null;
         return new ArtistaForm { Id = artista.Id, Nome = artista.nome };
     }

     
 }
 public class ArtistaRepository : GenericRepository<ArtistaModel>, IArtistaRepository
 {
     public ArtistaRepository(MvcProj8_0Context context) : base(context)
     {
     }

     public async Task<ArtistaModel> GetByIdAsync(string id)
     {
         return await _dbSet.FindAsync(id);
     }

    
 }
 public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
 {
     protected readonly MvcProj8_0Context _context;
     protected readonly DbSet<T> _dbSet;

     public GenericRepository(MvcProj8_0Context context)
     {
         _context = context;
         _dbSet = context.Set<T>();
     }

     public async Task AddAsync(T entity)
     {
         await _dbSet.AddAsync(entity);
         await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
     }

     public async Task DeleteAsync(T entity)
     {
         _dbSet.Remove(entity);
         await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
     }

     public async Task UpdateAsync(T entity)
     {
         _dbSet.Update(entity);
         await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
     }

     public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync()
     {
         return await _dbSet.ToListAsync();
     }

     public async Task<T> GetByIdAsync(string id)
     {
         return await _dbSet.FindAsync(id);
     }
 }

Controller
    public class ArtistaController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IArtistaService _artistaService;

    public ArtistaController(IArtistaService artistaService)
    {
        _artistaService = artistaService;
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ArtistaModel>> Get(string id)
    {
        var artista = await _artistaService.GetAsync(id);
        if (artista == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(artista);
    }

}

DataBaseFixture
public class DataBaseFixture : IDisposable
{
    public MvcProj8_0Context Context { get; private set; }

    public DataBaseFixture()
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MvcProj8_0Context>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            
            .Options;

        Context = new MvcProj8_0Context(options);
        
        SeedDatabase();
    }

    private void SeedDatabase()
    {
        Context.Artista.AddRange(
            new ArtistaModel { Id = "1", nome = "Oda" },
            new ArtistaModel { Id = "2", nome = "Echiro" },
            new ArtistaModel { Id = "3", nome = "Echiro Oda" }
        );
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
        Context.Dispose();
    }
}

Test
public class ArtistaControllerTest : IClassFixture<DataBaseFixture>
  {
      private readonly DataBaseFixture _fixture;
      private readonly ArtistaController _controller;

      public ArtistaControllerTest(DataBaseFixture fixture)
      {
          _fixture = fixture;

          // Setup the repository and service using the in-memory context
          var artistaRepository = new ArtistaRepository(_fixture.Context);
          var artistaService = new ArtistaService(artistaRepository);

          // Initialize the controller with the actual service
          _controller = new ArtistaController(artistaService);
      }

      [Fact]
      public async Task GetArtista()
      {
          var artistaId = "1";
          var expectedArtista = new ArtistaForm { Id = artistaId, Nome = "Oda" };

          var result = await _controller.Get(artistaId);

          // Assert
          var okResult = Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(result.Result);
          var returnValue = Assert.IsType<ArtistaForm>(okResult.Value);
          Assert.Equal(expectedArtista.Id, returnValue.Id);
          Assert.Equal(expectedArtista.Nome, returnValue.Nome);
      }

    
  }


Thanks! The solution worked perfectly.
